# Why was the question about billionaires buying life insurance closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This is the question I'm talking about:

[Why do billionaires buy life insurance?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/43140/10997)

I understand that the user asking the question has a self-serving agenda.  However, this particular question is worded in such a way that it really does invite unbiased answers.  In fact, the question has a very good, well received answer that seems to contradict the OP's views.

Why was this question closed?  If a different user had asked the same question using the same words, would it have been left open?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't close it, and I wouldn't delete it (due to the quality answer), but that question is either

1. Answered elsewhere on the site
2. Tends towards being chatty

While I kind of agree the question at its face is answerable, (in fact JohnFX gave a pretty good answer), *that particular* question is a concealed marketing pitch, and that kind of intent very likely isn't going to leave a good Q&A.  (IMO, and apparently JoeT's and Dilip)

The closing vote from JoeTaxpayer was explained.  I would also invite you to re-open if you really think there are more or better answers out there.

I won't reopen it myself because it is already answered, and ***probably*** just going to become a comment war.

> *As I am typing this, the OP came back with a couple "well actually" responses and it making claims as if they were facts.*

I could be wrong about that; it is just my gut feeling.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts; I really do appreciate the explanation.  A couple of questions based on your answer: (1) Does closing a question prevent a comment war?  I thought comments were still allowed on closed questions. (2) Is the fact that a question has a good answer a basis for closing the question? I've upvoted JohnFx's answer already, and I don't have anything to add at this time, but there probably is more to say on the subject.  I'd vote to reopen, but I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: @BenMiller (1) Closed questions fade off of the homepage.  Out of site, out of mind.  (2) We close stuff to follow the directions and guidelines of the community.  We delete stuff to remove crap.  I personally wouldn't delete that question because I think it probably "Makes the Internet Better," but it stays closed because the potential for spoilage is high.

Comment: There are times a question strikes me a certain way, and I refrain from action. Mods have no "vote" just a close option. In my opinion, the OP's intentions were not genuine. His profile shows he's an insurance salesman. As I commented, does he really not know why he's selling his own product? When Dilip voted to close, I decided I was comfortable to offer my closing vote. After seeing OP's latest comments, I'm inclined to refrain from further dialog. i.e. The question can be voted to re-open, with me abstaining.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks for your comments.  I agree that the OP's intentions are not genuine, and that further dialog with him is not productive.  However, simply reading the text of the question, I wondered if someone else had posted an identical question, without the history of the other posts, would this question have been closed?

Comment: @BenMiller - There were 2 close votes before I shut it. If I had a simple vote, I suspect 2 more would have finished it off. It's possible that another OP might have had the question stay open. It's also possible for a pro-wholelife member to present an objective case advocating this product. The OP's latest response to an old question has (IMHO) a remarkably low signal to noise ratio. My high school English teacher would have redlined the whole article. "citation?" "unsubstantiated generality" "Several reasons? What are they?" I'd still welcome the counterpoint advocate.