# Are questions about market regulation ontopic, even if it is about regulation pertaining companies?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic

For example, a question about the regulation on illegal insider trading. It is something that can be done by company executives or the company itself, but is not directly related to [own?] personal finance.

Even so, it is an issue that has direct effect on securities values, therefore an effect on personal finance as well.

Maybe it falls under [finacial-literacy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finacial-literacy)?

Comment: Related: [Is it required for a question to apply personally to the asker in order to be considered on-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2076/10997)

Answer (score 2):

Some Question on market regulation are on topic.

> a question about the regulation on illegal insider trading

This is on topic and we have few question on this; more to understand at a broad level as this would help understand the risks involved in stocks or would help an individual better understand certain companies.

Similar question are on what happens to Minority stake holders, their rights and protection ... most of these are regulations.

There could be other set of regulations in respect of running a company, these would be off-topic.